# Dense algebraic curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-topology

Let's assume we are given $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology (unions of open balls).

We call a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ dense, if $\forall U \underset{open}{\subset} \mathbb{R}^2 \ \Rightarrow \ A \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Let's further assume we are given a degree $d$ algebraic variety
$$A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |\sum_{i,j=0}^d a_{ij}x^iy^j=0 \quad i+j \leq d \}$$

We assume $d$ to be finite but it can be arbitrarily large. My question is the following: Can the algebraic curve $A$ be dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

---

I think it cannot be dense. My idea of a proof is that $A$ would need infinitely many intersections. If it only has finite intersection I think it cannot be dense. However such an algebraic curve always has only finitely many intersections.

Comment: Suppose that it is dense: since the polynomial is a continuous function and vanishes on a dense set...

Comment: Take any point $(x, y)$ where $\sum \not = 0$. There exists a neighbourhood of this point that does not intersect $A$. Another way to say it: $A$ is closed, so if it was dense, it would be equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial answer is yes: If all the $a_{ij}$ are zero, then $A = \mathbb R^2$ is dense.

But if at least one of the $a_{ij} \neq 0$, then $A$ is not dense:
The function $f(x,y) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} x^i y^j$ is a continuous map $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. This means that the preimage $f^{-1}(0) = A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$. But if some of the $a_{ij}$ are non-zero, then the map $f$ is not the zero map (to see this, restrict $f$ to an appropriate line $L$, so that $f|_L$ is non-zero polynomial, hence non-zero as a function on $L$). So there is a point $p \notin A$. But since $A$ is closed, $\mathbb R^2 \setminus A$ is open, so there is a ball around $p$ which is fully contained in $\mathbb R^2 \setminus A$. This means that $A$ is not dense.